# Having problems while trying to upload an image using Retrofit multi-part android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm getting the following 405 not allowed error message on onResponse while trying to upload an image on the api server, the api receives an api token, "_method":"PUT" and image url as parameters, everything else is optional, any help would be appreciated, code is listed below thanks.

> Response{protocol=http/1.0, code=405, message=Method Not Allowed, url=http://ec2-35-161-195-128.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/account}

Interface:

```
public interface UserSignUpClient {

@POST("account")
Call<AuthenticationAccountCreationResponse> createAccount(@Body UserSignUp userSignUp);

@Multipart
@POST("account")
Call<UserInfo> postImage(@Header("Authorization") String headerValue, @PartMap Map<String, String> map, @PartMap Map<String, String> imageMap, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
}
```

Retrofit builder class:

```
public class RestClient {

private UserSignInClient userSignInClient;
private UserSignUpClient userSignUpClient;
private UserInfoClient userInfoClient;

public RestClient(String baseUrlLink){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseUrlLink)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    if (baseUrlLink.equals(CONSTS.BASE_URL_ADDRESS_TOKEN)){

        userSignInClient = retrofit.create(UserSignInClient.class);
    } else if (baseUrlLink.equals(CONSTS.BASE_URL_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT_CREATION)) {

        userSignUpClient = retrofit.create(UserSignUpClient.class);
    } else if (baseUrlLink.equals(CONSTS.BASE_URL_ADDRESS_USER_INFO)){

        userInfoClient = retrofit.create(UserInfoClient.class);
    }
}

public UserSignInClient getUserSignInClient() {
    return userSignInClient;
}

public UserSignUpClient getUserSignUpClient() {
    return userSignUpClient;
}

public UserInfoClient getUserInfoClient() {
    return userInfoClient;
}
}
```

Main Class:

```
userImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            galleryIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
        }
    });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        String filePath = FileUtils.getPath(this, selectedImageUri);
        file = new File(filePath);
        image_name = file.getName();

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {

            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(AUTHORIZATION);

                sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.token), 0);
                stringBuilder.append(sharedPreferences.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.token), ""));

                methodMap.put("_method", "PUT");
                imageMap.put("image", file.getName());

                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);

                Call<UserInfo> uploadImage = new RestClient(CONSTS.BASE_URL_ADDRESS_ACCOUNT_CREATION).getUserSignUpClient()
                        .postImage(stringBuilder.toString(), methodMap, imageMap, body);

                uploadImage.enqueue(new Callback<UserInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UserInfo> call, Response<UserInfo> response) {

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UserInfo> call, Throwable t) {

                        Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

postman api image = https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1BHX.png

Comment: So what kind of method is allowed? Because your code shows POST while you write PUT.

Comment: main method is POST but "_method":"PUT" parameter lets you upload the image, without _method it becomes a POST message and every other parameter than becomes compulsory, please check the image.

Comment: Did you try encoding your partmap parameters object?

Comment: encoding, please elaborate?